# Which radio technology for long distance, high(er) power, IP traffic?

Tags: wireless, lora

I'm looking to build a long distance IP star network using one of the IoT PHY layers but unsure if LoRa is right. An ideal solution would be something to the effect of 915Mhz WiFi or WiFi HaLow however I'm seeking lower data rates < 1Mbps and maximum signal reflection in rural areas.

In an environment where power isn't an issue, think a radio handset connected to a laptop - which of the IoT radio layers offer reasonable power, low enough frequency and easy enough to present as a network interface on a computer.

Comment: You will have to be a bit more specific in terms of bandwidth requirements (1 Mbps is waaaaaay over the capabilities of LoRa, so it makes a real difference if you actually mean a few Kbps or close to 1 Mbps), both peak and average (in many regions there are duty cycle limits which drop average bandwidth even more for LoRa), the kind of distances, whether you will have line of sight, the region you are in (power limits vary a lot), whether that is for a fixed or mobile link, etc. Running IP over LoRa is quite a challenge given the constraints (very low bandwidth, small packet sizes…).

Comment: Thanks @jcaron - target bandwidth would be 1mbps with an IP stack over it with the idea of maximising range in a rural environment.

Comment: How far is “maximising range”? Kilometres? Tens of kilometres? Hundreds? You should probably look into WiMAX and other similar technologies, but having antennas as high as possible (especially the centre of the star) to ensure line of sight will be key. You may also need directional antennas and careful positioning of those. Note that you are likely to require a license, depending on what region you are in and what technology you pick.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the technology best suited to my requirements is NPR (New Packet Radio) which is a DMR-like TDMA protocol that uses a small RF transceiver module and a TDMA capable amplifier for range and can achieve speeds of around 500kbps usable.

[Build a Long-Distance Data Network Using Ham Radio Send data via IPv4 up to 300 kilometers with easy-to-assemble hardware](https://spectrum.ieee.org/build-a-longdistance-data-network-using-ham-radio)

Comment: You still haven’t told us in which region you are. You mentioned the 915 MHz band which is non-EU in your question, but this is 433 MHz-based, which is mostly only EU. Also the article says the regulations allow for 60 ms bursts but they went for 80 ms minimum. I’m far from certain this actually matches your needs.

Comment: A quick look at 433 MHz regulations in the US and EU (which are extremely different) makes me seriously doubt it is suitable for your application (at least what I can guess about it given what little information you have provided) given transmit time/duty cycle limitations and very low maximum power.